# How can I get a string from a function I made to be stored in a global variable I have in my main program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope, output

I am trying to store the data of a variable of a function in a variable in my main program. The goal of this program is to ask for an input(Authors name) and add spaces if the length of the value satisfies the condition of it being less than a value, in this case whatever is stored in numb(16).

My function code is this:

```
def AddSpaces(auth,numb):
    print("Runs")
    while len(auth) < numb:
        auth = auth + " "
    print(auth)
```

I'm using it for this:

```
Author = str(input("Author: "))
AddSpaces(Author,16)
print(Author)
```

The output of the function would be "Author.........." but for the program It's "Author".
How can I get auth to be stored in Author? Thank you.

Comment: You should avoid globals. Just return `auth` from your function and assign it to `Author` -- `Author = AddSpaces(Author,16)`

Comment: Many beginners have a hard time understanding the difference between what a function *prints* and what it *returns.* You probably want to explore this difference, and likely change your function so it doesn't print anything, and leave the decision to print something or not to the caller.

Comment: you can use `" " * 16` to get 16 spaces in Python...

Comment: BTW, you do not need any loops. All you need is `auth = auth + " " * (numb - len(auth))`.

Comment: you can simply use **auth.ljust(abs(len(auth)-numb))**

Comment: @Abdulla Alzaabi String is an immutable object so if you pass it to another function and change the variable value it won't change the value in callers variable you need to return the value from the function and reassign it to Author variable

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value from the function instead of printing it. Also, your function is implemented very inefficiently. Use format strings instead of the loop:

```
def add_spaces(auth, numb):
    return f"{auth:{numb}s}"
```

Do not call `str()`, `input` already returns a string. And do not capitalize variable names, this is against Python style guide:

```
author = input("Author: ")
author_with_spaces = add_spaces(author, 16)
print(author_with_spaces)
```